# JSON.parse gives error on Chrome but working fine with Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

The code below works as expected on Firefox but gives following error on Chrome, how could that be?

VM317:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse ()

**Script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cat").click(function(){
        var cat=$.trim($(this).html());
        var data=localStorage.getItem("data");
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        var $html='';
        for(var i=0 ; i<data.length ; i++){

            if((data[i]['tags'].toLowerCase()).includes("#"+cat.toLowerCase())){
                $html+='<div class="podcast">';
                *//some more html*
            }
        }
        $("#listediv").html( $html );
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem("data") === null) {
        $.post( "ajax.php", { all: true })
            .done(function( data ) {
                localStorage.setItem("data", data);
        });
    }
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
$html='';
include 'db_connection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();
if(isset($_POST['all'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM db ";
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $return_row =array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $r=array();
        $r['name']=$row['name'];
        $r['description']=$row['description'];
        $return_row[]=$r;
    }
    echo json_encode($return_row);
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: You may have to show us the JSON that you were processing when you got the error.

Comment: It's the entries from mysql db

Comment: Your script.js is missing a finishing `}`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM db` Do you really have a Table in your database called `db`?? Or are you trying to query the whole db?

Comment: i changed the table name, for the sake of posting here.

Comment: I just copy pasted some part of the code, could be that some paranthesis are missing above. I don't have syntax issues on the code and everything works fine with Firefox. Looks like, only on chrome browser there is problem parsing json data here `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Well all that parses is the data you have (**or have not**) already placed in localstorage

Comment: Right, I'm not sure how to debug this further.

Comment: Run with the browser js debugger. Set a breadpoint on the line before that line. Use debugger to look at what is in localstorage

Comment: Found out that nothing is in the data storage, that seems to be the reason. But why the data is there on Firefox and not on Chrome?

Comment: Did you also check that the `if (localStorage.getItem("data") === null) {` is ever running

Answer (score 0):

Chrome show error if result empty try

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data") || "[]")
```